# How can several vector layers have different controls, using Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, point, line

Using `openlayers` I have two vector layers. One layer is called `lineLayer` consisting of vector lines, and the other is called `pointLayer` consisting of points. When I hover on the lines I want to be able to highlight the line, and identify the vector object when I click on it. When I hover on the point I want to highlight the point and be able to drag it. My code works separately for lines and points, but not when I put it together.

This is how I manage the line layer:

```
// handle interactions with lines
var highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(lineLayer, {
    hover: true,
    highlightOnly: true,            
    renderIntent: "temporary"
});

map.addControl(highlightCtrl);
highlightCtrl.activate();

var selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(lineLayer, {      
    clickout: true, 
    onSelect: function(feature){console.log(feature)}       
});

map.addControl(selectCtrl);         
selectCtrl.activate();
```

And this is how I manage the points:

```
// handle interactions with points 
var highlightpoint = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(pointLayer, {
    hover: true,
    highlightOnly: true,
    renderIntent: "temporary",
});

map.addControl(highlightpoint);
highlightpoint.activate();

var dragStart = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(pointLayer, {
    autoActivate: true
}); 

map.addControl(dragStart);
dragStart.activate();
```

From reading other examples I have noticed that the order seems to matter when a control is added. However, I've tried all the possible combinations of layer adding, and it does not seem to make a difference.

Is there some way to do this that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass an array of layers to the select control

```
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    [lineLayer, pointLayer],
    {
        clickout: true, toggle: false,
        multiple: false, hover: false,
        toggleKey: "ctrlKey", // ctrl key removes from selection
        multipleKey: "shiftKey" // shift key adds to selection
    }
);

map.addControl(selectControl);
selectControl.activate();
```

See the [openlayers documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature)

To add different behavior for each layer, you could use the "featureselected" and "featureunselected" like in [this](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html) example

**EDIT**

How to handle both click and hover control? I didn't try, but following this example should be done easily. Notice that the "hover" control is nothing else that a select control with 'hover': true. So, just add another control passing to it  the array of layers.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have different functionality for each layer which is why I separated them.

Comment: You can register a "featureselected" and "featureunselected" event for each layer....I attach another link in the answer

Comment: Thank you, this works well for selected features when clicked. I'm still not managing to make it work for a feature that is highlighted, as I want to call a function when this occurs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can even do it all in 1 function and just differentiate between layers by checking which one it is:
To decide what to do with the selected feature, you can use this in your callback

```
function onFeatureSelect(event) {
...
var feature = event.feature;
...
// Now you know what to do since you know what layer this fired.
 if ( strcmp ('BadLayer', feature.layer.name) == 0 ) {
   // Do nothing for this layer !
   return true;
  }
}
```

Btw, that strcmp is not a standard javascript, just in case you use it, you'll need this too:

```
function strcmp (str1, str2) {
     return ((str1 == str2) ? 0 : ((str1 > str2) ? 1 : -1));
}
```

The point is that you cannot use more than 1 OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature and expect them to function 'per layer'.

It's actually intented not to work anymore, apparently you cannot create 2 Control features.  Instead you need to create one and apply this to both layers.  The support for this was [removed in 2.7 as stated in the docs](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/overlays.html#interaction).  There is a good example of how to do this with [2 different Vector Layers](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html).
This took me days to realise.